# What happens when a MySQL connection is not closed?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if MySQL connections continually aren't closed on PHP pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103281/what-happens-if-mysql-connections-continually-arent-closed-on-php-pages)

If you forget sometimes to close the connection will be close in a while, automatically or will be stay open?

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
.
.
your code
.
.
and you forget to mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103281/what-happens-if-mysql-connections-continually-arent-closed-on-php-pages

Comment: the connection is closed when the page completes anyways, but it is good practice to close the connection when your done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`mysql_connect()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) documentation:

> Note
>
> The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling [`mysql_close()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php).

PS. You should consider moving to [PDO](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or at least [mysqli](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) driver.

Comment: good advise about PDO and mysqli

Comment: I would also recommend PDO...

Answer (score 4):

MySQL connections are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php).